# Change attributes' values based on geometry relation

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, geometry

### **MY GOAL IN A NUTSHELL**

I am trying to calculate the angles between lines. For doing this, I calculated the lines' slop respect to x axis and now I am trying to subtract them to find the angle inside. I implemented the equation in Python (and for now I don't want to deal with modules like shapely or fiona but I am looking 
for simple Python scripts to get confidence).

### **PROBLEM**

In the attribute table, data only for one feature is filled.
[image]

### **SCRIPT TRIAL**

```
import itertools
layer.startEditing()
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("ang_vertex",QVariant.Double)])
layer.updateFields()
layer.commitChanges()

layer.startEditing()
field=layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('ang_vertex')
print field
for geom1,geom2 in itertools.permutations(layer.getFeatures(),r=2):
    if geom1.geometry().touches(geom2.geometry()):
        equation=geom1[3]-geom2[3]
        print feat[2], equation
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), field, equation)
layer.updateFields()
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: I think the issue is because `layer.updateFields()` should be inside the loop and if statement.

Comment: If you only use PyQGIS, you don't need Shapely or Fiona

Comment: @xunilk actually, no. I suppose that the problem could be related **either** to the fact that I call geometry 1and 2 so maybe it doesn't truely iterate among all geometries **or** that I don't call attributes...it's just an hypothesis, maybe wrong...